# How to mix $n$ litres of water at desired temp

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As a fishkeeper, I would like an efficient way to mix say $25$ litres of water by using $X$ amount of tap water at $10-15$ degrees $C$ and kettle water of $100 C$. At the moment I'm guessing and tinkering will excel. In my head I've figured out that I need the ratio of $n$ parts of $A$ to $n$ parts of $B$.  So I may have $3:2$ ratio  so that's $5$ parts in total.  So I need to divide desired litres($25$)  by $5$ to get the multiplier of $5$. So my proportion is $15:10$.

What I'm struggling with is how do I plug in the desired temp. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, I feel like I've been hypnotized to count to ten but told there's no such number $7$. My spreadsheet takes the input volumes and Temps and gives me the output litres and temperature and I have to tweak each input (goal seeking) to get my desired output. 
I hope this isn't too simple for anyone to help me or to tell me off.

Answer (score 1):

You need both of the following to hold true:

1)  desired temp = [(amount of tap water)* 10 + (amount of kettle water) * 100]/25

AND

2)  25= (amount of tap water) + (amount of kettle water).

---

Solving for amount of kettle water in the second equation you find:

25-(amount of tap water) = (amount of kettle water)

Substituting this into initial equation:

desired temp = (amount of tap water)* 10/25 + (25-(amount of tap water)) * 100/25

**

Rearranging for a more desirable solution:

(amount of tap water)= [5(desired temp) - 500 ]/ (-18)

**
Example: If desired temp was 60C then you would need 11.11L of tap water.

Comment: Should that 250 be 2500?

Comment: I had a couple mistakes. Thank you @saulspatz for catching my algebra errors. All corrected now

Comment: Thanks Maggie it works, I'm baffled by what the apparent constants 5, -18 and 500 are but it works perfectly. I tried to leave feedback votes but not sure how that works either.

Comment: Can someone explain to me what area of maths this is and how one would go about finding a solution for myself. Is this basic algebra, I can see there's some averages,ratios and simultaneous equations there. What I can't really get is that I have two different staritng temperatures and want to achieve a specific intermediate value and how I get there, I thought I would be deducting the lower temp from the higher temp and dividing that by desired temp to get a fraction to work from.  I just understand.